# Calcular edad en días

Tags: c++

Me piden que elabore un programa que pida al usuario su fecha de nacimiento (en el formato
día, mes, año), así como la fecha actual, y calcule la edad del usuario en días. El
programa debe verificar que las fechas son correctas (ejemplo, 30/02/1998 y
10/13/1980 no lo son) y tomar en cuenta los años bisiestos, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, entré a esta página, pero no logro comprenerlo bien.

https://calcuonline.com/calculadoras/calculadora-edad/

esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora y no se como continuar,tenia la idea de definir los meses y restarlos a los años pero no se como hacerlo, algna ayuda?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int da,ma,aa,dn,md,an,i,cont,dias=0;
    cout<<"ingresa el dia actual: "<<endl; cin>>da;
    cout<<"ingresa el mes actual: "<<endl; cin>>ma;
    cout<<"ingresa el anio actual: "<<endl; cin>>aa;
    cout<<"ingresa tu dia de nacimiento: "<<endl; cin>>dn;
    cout<<"ingresa tu mes de nacimiento: "<<endl; cin>>md;
    cout<<"ingresa tu anio de nacimiento: "<<endl; cin>>an;
    for(int i=an;i<=aa;i++)
{
    if(i%4==0 and i%100!=0 or i%400==0)
    {
    int enero=31;
    int febrero=29;
    int marzo=31;
    int abril=30;
    int mayo=31;
    int junio=30;
    int julio=31;
    int agosto=31;
    int septiembre=30;
    int octubre=31;
    int noviembre=30;
    int diciembre=31;
    if 
    cout<<"bisiesto"<<i<<endl;
    cont=cont+366;
    }
    else{
    int enero=31;
    int febrero=28;
    int marzo=31;
    int abril=30;
    int mayo=31;
    int junio=30;
    int julio=31;
    int agosto=31;
    int septiembre=30;
    int octubre=31;
    int noviembre=30;
    int diciembre=31;
    cout<<"no bisiesto"<<i<<endl;
    cont=cont+365;
    }   
}   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] y te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El sitio no está pensado para que hagan los deberes escolares por ti. Debes demostrar un mínimo de esfuerzo, explicando con detalle el problema o dificultad encontrada y los memsajes de error de tu código. Mucho me temo que sin eso, tu pregunta termine cerrada. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Es muy fácil, restas de la fecha más antigua la fecha más reciente.

Comment: pero no es sacar la diferencia en años sino en días.

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar la diferencia en días, primero has de convertir las dos fechas a días. ¿no?

¿Y cómo se hace eso? Bueno, este problema no lo ha inventado tu profesor, viene de lejos. Eso quiere decir que ya hay funciones que hacen más o menos esto.

Por ejemplo, existe *unix timestamp*, que mide el número de segundos que han pasado desde el 1 de Enero de 1970. Si obtienes el timestamp de dos fechas diferentes y restas los resultados, obtendrás el número de segundos que separan ambas fechas. Convertir de segundos a días es trivial pues basta con hacer divisiones.

No creo que en tu caso te estén pidiendo que tires de estas ayudas sino que seas capaz de resolver el problema por tus propios medios. Así que vamos por partes. Conocer cuántos días hay entre dos fechas no sería un problema si no existiesen los años bisiestos, pero tampoco es que complique mucho la ecuación.

Se define como año bisiesto aquel en el que el año es divisible entre 4, salvo que sea divisible entre 100 o que sea directamente divisible entre 400.

```
bool es_bisiesto(int anio)
{ return (anio % 4 == 0 && anio % 100 != 0) || anio % 400 == 0; }
```

Fíjate que aquí no uso `and` ni `or`. Esos elementos no forman parte de los estándares actuales del lenguaje. Mejor no te acostumbres a ellos.

Volviendo al tema. Calcular el número de años bisiestos se puede reducir a iterar entre el año de origen y el de destino y verificar todos los años uno a uno:

```
int inicio = an+1;
int fin = aa-1;

int num_bisiestos = 0;
for( int anio=inicio; anio<=fin; anio++) 
{
    num_bisiestos += es_bisiesto(anio) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Por otro lado, calcular el número de día del año es algo que se puede obtener facilmente:

```
int dias_mes[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
int diaDelAnio = da;
for( int i=0; i<ma-1; i++ )
    diaDelAnio += dias_mes[i];
if( ma > 2 && es_bisiesto(aa) )
    diaDelAnio++;
```

Con este empuje deberías ser capaz de calcular la distancia en días que hay entre dos fechas.

Sugerencia: Usa nombres de variables más representativos. `aa` **no significa** absolutamente nada. Casi sería preferible que usases estructuras:

```
struct Fecha
{
  int dia;
  int mes;
  int anio;
};
```

Podrías entonces tener código tal que:

```
Fecha fecha1 = { 10, 1, 2020 } // 10 de Enero del 2020
std::cout << fecha1.dia << '\' << fecha1.mes << '\' << fecha1.anio;
```

Creo que esta opción es mucho más legible que la que tienes actualmente